# Why is it selecting both radio buttons?

Tags: html

With given HTML, it is selecting both radios despite of having same name that is **mode**

```
<div class="row margin-top">
    <div class="col-md-3 col-md-offset-1">
        <form action="" method="post">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label>
                    <input type="radio" value="keyword" name="mode">
                    Search by Keyword
                </label>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-5">
        <form action="" method="post">
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="text" name="keyword" class="form-control">
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row margin-top">
    <div class="col-md-11 col-md-offset-1">
        <form action="" method="post">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label>
                    <input type="radio" value="criteria" name="mode">
                    Search by Criteria
                </label>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: because they are in 2 different forms

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is because, both are in different `<form>`s. You need to have them in a single `<form>`. Kindly put them in a single `<form>` for the expected behaviour.

Multiple forms can have the same options. For eg., there can be individual forms with `Yes` and `No` options.

```html
<div>
  <form action="">
    <p>Do you have Item 1?</p>
    <label><input type="radio" name="has"> Yes</label>
    <label><input type="radio" name="has"> No</label>
  </form>
</div>
<div>
  <form action="">
    <p>Do you have Item 2?</p>
    <label><input type="radio" name="has"> Yes</label>
    <label><input type="radio" name="has"> No</label>
  </form>
</div>
<div>
  <form action="">
    <p>Do you have Item 3?</p>
    <label><input type="radio" name="has"> Yes</label>
    <label><input type="radio" name="has"> No</label>
  </form>
</div>
<div>
  <form action="">
    <p>Do you have Item 4?</p>
    <label><input type="radio" name="has"> Yes</label>
    <label><input type="radio" name="has"> No</label>
  </form>
</div>
<div>
  <form action="">
    <p>Do you have Item 5?</p>
    <label><input type="radio" name="has"> Yes</label>
    <label><input type="radio" name="has"> No</label>
  </form>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Because you are using radio button in 3 different forms. **Try to give in a single form**

Answer (score 0):

What are you trying to achieve there? It's not really clear.
You're using a form for each element, instead of one form for all of the elements, together.

You have the same name for all the radio elements, which means it will you will get only 1 value at the submitting of the form (post data).
You should give different names, and different id's in order to add javascript interactivity.